# Access Google Search API from outside GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-search-api

I would like to use The Search API, provided by Google for indexing our data and then search on it. The problem is that our application does not go inside GAE. I find way how to use datastore outside GAE, but cannot find how to use Search API outside GAE. The question is: is it really possible to use it from application outside GAE?

PS: we use java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, the Search API is not even available in the GAE's flexible environment. From [Search](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/migrating#search):

> The Search service is currently unavailable outside of the standard
>   environment. You can host any full-text search database such as
>   [ElasticSearch on Google Compute Engine](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/bitnami-launchpad/elasticsearch) and access it from both
>   the standard and flexible environments.